# Can I keep the formatting of the compiler output when handling it?

Tags: c++, bash, redirect, gcc, formatting

Whenever I call run GCC, it nicely formats its output (making filenames bold, note labels white, error labels red, etc.). However, when I want to redirect it and still keep it displayed, the formatting just disappears...

Example:

```
make                                    # The display is formatted
(...)
make |& tee >(xargs echo > example.out) # The display is not formatted
(...)
```

How can I redirect the output while keeping the original display formatted?

Comment: `make |& tee example.out` should be equivalent and much simpler.

Comment: Another non-answer, but this could help guide you to the solution: commands often modify their output when they detect their standard output is a terminal. In this case, `gcc` may provided formatted output (containing characters intended to be interpreted by the terminal), but not if it detects that it is writing to a pipe. There may be a way to force `gcc` to provide colorized output regardless of its standard output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says (`File: gcc-6.info,  Node: Diagnostic Message Formatting Options`):

> ### `-fdiagnostics-color`[=WHEN]
>
> Use color in diagnostics.  WHEN is `never`, `always`, or `auto`.
>   The default depends on how the compiler has been configured, it can
>   be any of the above WHEN options or also `never` if `GCC_COLORS`
>   environment variable isn't present in the environment, and `auto`
>   otherwise.  `auto` means to use color only when the standard error
>   is a terminal.

Comment: This is awesome :) Thank you!